# Looping to recode variables in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm fairly new to programming and I have a question on using loops to recode variables in a pandas data frame that I was hoping I could get some help with.

I want to recode multiple columns in a pandas data frame from units of seconds to minutes. I've written a simple function in python and then can copy and repeat it on each column which works, but I wanted to automate this. I appreciate the help.

The ivf.secondsUntilCC.xxx column contains the number of seconds until something happens. I want the new column ivf.minsUntilCC.xxx to be the number of minutes. The data frame name is data.

```
def f(x,y):
    return x[y]/60

data['ivf.minsUntilCC.500'] = f(data,'ivf.secondsUntilCC.500')

data['ivf.minsUntilCC.1000'] = f(data,'ivf.secondsUntilCC.1000')

data['ivf.minsUntilCC.2000'] = f(data,'ivf.secondsUntilCC.2000')

data['ivf.minsUntilCC.3000'] = f(data,'ivf.secondsUntilCC.3000')

data['ivf.minsUntilCC.4000'] = f(data,'ivf.secondsUntilCC.4000')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use vectorized approach:

```
In [27]: df
Out[27]:
        X  ivf.minsUntilCC.500  ivf.minsUntilCC.1000  ivf.minsUntilCC.2000  ivf.minsUntilCC.3000  ivf.minsUntilCC.4000
0  191365               906395                854268                701859                979647                914942
1  288577               300394                577555                880370                924162                897984
2   66705               493545                232603                682509                794074                204429
3  747828               504930                379035                 29230                410390                287327
4  926553               913360                657640                336139                210202                356649

In [28]: df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith('ivf.minsUntilCC.')] /= 60

In [29]: df
Out[29]:
        X  ivf.minsUntilCC.500  ivf.minsUntilCC.1000  ivf.minsUntilCC.2000  ivf.minsUntilCC.3000  ivf.minsUntilCC.4000
0  191365         15106.583333          14237.800000          11697.650000          16327.450000          15249.033333
1  288577          5006.566667           9625.916667          14672.833333          15402.700000          14966.400000
2   66705          8225.750000           3876.716667          11375.150000          13234.566667           3407.150000
3  747828          8415.500000           6317.250000            487.166667           6839.833333           4788.783333
4  926553         15222.666667          10960.666667           5602.316667           3503.366667           5944.150000
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10**6,(5,6)),
                  columns=['X','ivf.minsUntilCC.500', 'ivf.minsUntilCC.1000',
                           'ivf.minsUntilCC.2000',  'ivf.minsUntilCC.3000',
                           'ivf.minsUntilCC.4000'])
```

Explanation:

```
In [26]: df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith('ivf.minsUntilCC.')]
Out[26]:
   ivf.minsUntilCC.500  ivf.minsUntilCC.1000  ivf.minsUntilCC.2000  ivf.minsUntilCC.3000  ivf.minsUntilCC.4000
0               906395                854268                701859                979647                914942
1               300394                577555                880370                924162                897984
2               493545                232603                682509                794074                204429
3               504930                379035                 29230                410390                287327
4               913360                657640                336139                210202                356649
```